# How to include Facebook-SDK

Tags: symfony

I'm using an example of FOSUserBundle with FOSFacebookBundle. Hereon i have build my application.

The relevant Project Structure is like following:

```
src\ABC\MainBundle\
src\ABC\UserBundle\

src\ABC\MainBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php

src\ABC\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider.php

vendor\facebook\php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php
```

Part of the FacebookProvider:

```
use \BaseFacebook;
use \FacebookApiException;

class FacebookProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

protected $facebook;

public function __construct(BaseFacebook $facebook, $userManager, $validator)
{
    $this->facebook = $facebook;
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{           
    try {
        $fbdata = $this->facebook->api('/me');

...
```

As you can see there is the Facebook-Object already available.
What i want to do now is nearly the same, but in my DefaultController:

```
use \BaseFacebook;
use \FacebookApiException;

class DefaultController extends BaseController
{
   public function indexAction(){
      $facebook = new Facebook('key', 'secret');
      $fbfriends_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/friends');
...
```

But there i get the message

```
Fatal error: Class 'ABC\MainBundle\Controller\Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\src\ABC\MainBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line x
```

Why is that? How can i access the facebook-class from inside my defaultcontroller? If its already possible for the facebookprovider, why it aint possible for my controller?

any hints will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that problem is, that the facebook-class has no namespace and you have to do something like

```
$facebook = new \Facebook(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
use \BaseFacebook;
use \FacebookApiException;
```

You are importing BaseFacebook class from namespace you should use \Facebook (in Controller and FacebookProvider classes)